# Cannot acess properties of Worksheet object in ExcelApi 1.7 and 1.8

Tags: office-js, excel-addins

According to the documentation, class Excel.Worksheet has several new properties in API v1.7 and v1.8. One of these properties is "showGridlines".

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.worksheet?view=office-js#freezepanes

I refer to the 'evergreen' office-js API in index.html, which I understand should include Excel API v1.8 (?):

```
<script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/Office.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I build a test function using the code example provided in the documentation for this property, and I added a snippet to ensure that the proper API version is supported. (See code below).

```
    public async test() {

        if (!Office.context.requirements.isSetSupported('ExcelApi', '1.8')) {
            console.error("Excel API v1.8 not supported!");
        }
        else {
            console.log("Excel API v1.8 is checked!");
        }

        await Excel.run(async (context) => {
            const sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
            //sheet.showGridlines = true;

            await context.sync();
        });
}
```

When I call the function (with the property assignment commented out), I get the expected console message that Excel API v1.8 is supported: Excel API v1.8 is checked!.

However, if I uncomment the assignment to sheet.showGridlines (thus falling back verbatim on the example given in the doc), I get a compilation error:

TS2339: Property 'showGridlines' does not exist on type 'Worksheet'.

It seems that these new additions to the API are not actually present in the code yet.

Any help appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: After some digging around, I found the solution, so I'll answer my own question. I am using TypeScript instead of vanilla JavaScript, which means that when using Office.js the "type definitions" must be locally present in a file called Office.d.ts at the root of the project. The procedure is described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/convert-javascript-to-typescript

Comment: yes, you need to keep the definitions updated to see proper intellisense.  With a node-based project (e.g., if you used Yeoman), you can just keep updated using the package from `npm install @types/office-js --save-dev`.  But if you are using VS and a converted TS project, you'll need to manually keep updating the copied-over file every so often, as you saw in the instructions.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I tried installing the types package as you suggested, and removing the types definition file (Office.d.ts) from the root of the project, but then I get back the compilation errors I had originally: TS2339: Property 'showGridlines' does not exist on type 'Worksheet'. For now I'll leave the file at the root of the project.